# Why is this proof attempt incorrect?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I am sorry for what is a sorry attempt at a complicated theorem but I was thinking about this problem and wanted to know what was wrong with this argument. This is an attempt of a proof of Bertrand's Postulate:

Let $f\left(x\right)=\pi\left(2x\right)-\pi\left(x\right)$. Take some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\pi\left(2m\right)-\pi\left(m\right)>2$. Let's examine the case of $f\left(m+1\right)$.

By the parameters of our assumption, it is clear that $2m+2$ is even and thus $\pi\left(2m\right)\leq\pi\left(2m+2\right)\leq\left(\pi\left(2m\right)+1\right)$. Similarly for the second term one can see that $\pi\left(m\right)\leq\pi\left(m+1\right)\leq\left(\pi\left(m\right)+1\right)$. Now we may examine cases:

$\textbf{Case 1:} \  \pi\left(2m+2\right)=\pi\left(2m\right)+1$ and $\pi\left(m+1\right)=\pi\left(m\right)$.

We see $$\pi\left(2m+2\right)-\pi\left(m+1\right)=\pi\left(2m\right)+1-\pi\left(m\right)>3$$

$\textbf{Case 2:} \ \pi\left(2m+2\right)=\pi\left(2m\right)$ and $\pi\left(m+1\right)=\pi\left(m\right)+1$.

From this, $$\pi\left(2m+2\right)-\pi\left(m+1\right)=\pi\left(2m\right)-\pi\left(m\right)-1>1$$

$\textbf{Case 3:} \ \pi\left(2m+2\right)=\pi\left(2m\right)+1$ and $\pi\left(m+1\right)=\pi\left(m\right)+1$.

Then, $$\pi\left(2m+2\right)-\pi\left(m+1\right)=\pi\left(2m\right)+1-\pi\left(m\right)-1>2$$

$\textbf{Case 4:} \ \pi\left(2m+2\right)=\pi\left(2m\right)$ and $\pi\left(m+1\right)=\pi\left(m\right)$.

This case is equivalent to the assumption.

From these four cases we can conclude that since $\pi\left(18\right)-\pi\left(9\right)=3$ that Bertrand's Postulate is true for $m\geq9$, our course we can manually check $m<9$ for completeness.

Sorry for this again but I appreciate your time.

Comment: Try stating your induction hypothesis when you are proving by induction. Here, you've concluded that if $f(m)>2$ then $f(m+1)>1$. Do you see why that might be a problem?

Comment: All you have is that $f(m)\geq 3\implies$ $  f(m+1)\geq 2.$  Similarly $f(m+1)\geq 2\implies$ $ f(m+2)\geq 1$  $\implies  f(m+3)\geq 0 $. But $f(m+3)\geq 0$  is trivial .... You might note that there are many non-negative integer-valued functions $g$ for which $|g(n+1)-g(n)|\leq 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$ and $g(n)>2$ for some $n$  but for which  $g(n)=0 $ for many $n.$